# How to make a navigation tree under the current view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a question about iphone split navigation?

First the app have not tabs.
When i tap the right top category button, the current view will move to the right,and show the navigation three,it looks like a uitableview and under the current view.
and then,when i select the table row,the current view will move back,and reload the view class.

It works like a tab.
But the tableview replace the tab ,and under the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something  like the [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController) project on github.